# Does the verb began have to change to past perfect

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

She said,"I strongly believe that Charity ***began*** smoking last month." Change to reported speeech.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum, Simba.
"She said she strongly believed that Charity had begun smoking in the previous month." Yes, I think you should use the past perfect here, as the embedded clause refers to a past prior to the one referred to in the main clause.